# Convert a String into Variable in Flutter - Text Widget

Tags: string, flutter, text

I want to display a text widget using dynamic values in flutter app.

Here's my code.

```
class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  var descVar; 
  @override
  void initState() {
    var pick = widget.classDesc;
    var picker = "ClassesInfo."+pick;
    setState(() {
      descVar = picker;
      print(descVar);
    });
  }
...
```

In the build:

`Text('${this.descVar}')`

I wish to get value from external file:

```
class ClassesInfo {  
  static const String desc_class1 = "Sahaja Yoga";
}
```

I am just getting the string output, but not the value from the variable!

Desired Output : Sahaja Yoga

Getting Now: ClassesInfo.desc_class1

Even if i print the value in class it is getting : ClassesInfo.desc_class1

Answer (score 1):

as i understood you want to print in text field value of desc_class const. So you can simply write:

```
Text(ClassesInfo.desc_class1)
```

Comment: Or even `Text(ClassesInfo.desc_class1)` (without string Interpolation)

Comment: I tried but not getting it. Since my variable is dynamic, i can't write simply Text(ClassesInfo.desc_class1). if I hardcore the value I am getting the result though. :(

Comment: If I write Text("${ClassesInfo.desc_class1}"), I think flutter is getting it as Text(ClassesInfo.desc_class1) and  is assuming it as text and not variable, thus it prints as it is.